# SwiftUI AVPlayer Error Reporting/Handling

Tags: swift, swiftui, error-handling, streaming

I've created a media app, which plays music via HTTP live stream in SwiftUI. The code (snippet) looks like following:

```
struct PlayerView: View {
  @State var audioPlayer: AVPlayer!
  @State var buttonSymbol: String = "pause.circle.fill"
  let url: URL!

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Sound")
      HStack {
        Button(action: {
          if self.audioPlayer.rate != 0.0 {
            self.buttonSymbol = "play.circle.fill"
            self.audioPlayer.pause()
          } else {
            self.buttonSymbol = "pause.circle.fill"
            self.audioPlayer.play()
          }
        }) {
          Image(systemName: self.buttonSymbol)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
      }
    }
    .onAppear {let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

      do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, policy: AVAudioSession.RouteSharingPolicy.longFormAudio, options: [])
      } catch let error {
        fatalError("*** Unable to set up the audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }

      let item = AVPlayerItem(url: self.url)
      self.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

      audioSession.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
          fatalError("An error occurred: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
          return
        }

        self.audioPlayer.play()
      }

    }
  }
}
```

My lack of understanding is, how do I receive the underlying AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem errors (for instance the HTTP stream is interrupted) in SwiftUI in order to show them in the UI? Which SwiftUI action I have to use and how?

Comment: You could declare a `@State var theError: String?` or something similar (e.g. theError: MyError?).
 Then, instead of `fatalError(...)`, update the `theError`. After that
 display it in an popup alert, or something similar when `theError` is not nil.

Comment: No, that's not the question! During streaming errors may occur, how to catch and handle them? Your suggestion means only the setup, but how to handle these case is obvious to me.

Comment: Ok, I see, the doc at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer
 indicates there are two approaches to observe a player’s state, in particular the `addPeriodicTimeObserver`.
Maybe use something like,  `if player?.currentItem?.status == ...`

Comment: I am aware of the status field, nevertheless thank you. Actually I am interested in a SwiftUI solution where an action is called (together with some sample code). I don't want to poll the status, because this is waste of CPU resources IMHO. Some sample code would be really helpful because I am a SwiftUI beginner. Furthermore I think putting some links here wan't help other SwiftUI beginners.

Comment: Suit yourself, if you don't want to use `addPeriodicTimeObserver`.
 Maybe someone will find a better approach. Since my links were not helpfull,
 I will not present another (with some example code).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem) `AVPlayerItem` has a notification called **AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime**.

One possible implementation in a `Viewmodel` would be:

```
import Combine

....

playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeObserver = NotificationCenter
            .default
            .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime)
            .sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] notification in
               // handle notification here
            })
```

You would need to hold a reference to `playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeObserver` else it will go out of scope as soon as the method calling this finished.